# Downloading a File from JupyterHub to a Windows Path programmatically

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to Download a File from JupyterHub to a Windows Path programmatically. It gets downloaded to the home folder of Jupyterhub. however I want the notebooks output to save individuals download folder. I searched for library or code but I didnt find it anywhere. Can anyone let me know how to do it

```
path2 = R"C:/Users/xyd/Downloads"
print(path2)
df_coverage.to_excel(path2+'/'+'Data_03.xlsx')
```

It gives me error OSError: Cannot save file into a non-existent directory: 'C:\Users\xyd\Downloads'